# Starting a new thread in Gui application python

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, python-multithreading

I've got a python Gui application which has a thread that does some updating.
This is how its implemented.

```
GObject.threads_init()
Class main:
    #Extra stuff here
    update_thread = Thread(target= update_func, args=(Blah blah,))
    update_thread.setDaemon(True)
    update_thread.start()
    Gtk.main()
```

This is how the update_func looke like

```
def update_func():
    try:
        #do updating
        time.sleep(#6hrs)
    except:
        #catch error 
        time.sleep(#5 min)
    finally:
        update_func()
```

The thread runs as long as the program is running and the program I have runs for days
The problem is that sometimes the thread dies and updates do not occur and I have to restart the application.

Is there a way to start a new thread if the current one dies, especially in a Gui application?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a thread example snipped from one of my gtk apps. It might be helpful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Copyright (C) 2013 LiuLang <gsushzhsosgsu@gmail.com>

# Use of this source code is governed by GPLv3 license that can be found
# in http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html


from gi.repository import GObject
from gi.repository import Gtk
import threading

#UPDATE_INTERVAL = 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000   # 6 hours
UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000   # 2 secs, for test only

def async_call(func, func_done, *args):
    '''
    Call func in another thread, without blocking gtk main loop.

    `func` does time-consuming job in background, like access website.
    If `func_done` is not None, it will be called after func() ends.
    func_done is called in gtk main thread, and this function is often used
    to update GUI widgets in app.
    `args` are parameters for func()
    '''
    def do_call(*args):
        result = None
        error = None

        try:
            result = func(*args)
        except Exception as e:
            error = e

        if func_done is not None:
            GObject.idle_add(lambda: func_done(result, error))

    thread = threading.Thread(target=do_call, args=args)
    thread.start()

class App(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.set_default_size(480, 320)
        self.set_border_width(5)
        self.set_title('Gtk Threads')
        self.connect('delete-event', self.on_app_exit)

        self.update_timer = GObject.timeout_add(UPDATE_INTERVAL,
                self.check_update)

    def run(self):
        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def on_app_exit(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def check_update(self):
        def _do_check_update():
            print('do check update: will check for updating info')
            print(threading.current_thread(), '\n')

        print('check update')
        print(threading.current_thread())
        async_call(_do_check_update, None)
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.run()
```